# What is the meaning of the bound_array and the radius parameter from node_data array of the kdtree implementation?

Tags: scikit-learn, kdtree

The information of already created KDTree is in the data-array, bound-array, node_data-array and idx-array. I am wondering how i can use only the information in these arrays to find the points of some leaf-node which are closest to a given input-point? I want only to understand the big picture of using these arrays and not using some build-in-functions like query etc...

So in each node_array there are 4 values: start_index, end_index, is_leaf, radius. With the start_index, end_index and the idx_array i can find the indices of the points that belongs to a certain leaf_node from the tree. Right now I am wondering what is the meaning of the bound_array? I know that for every tree_node there is lower and upper bound in the bound_array, but how i can use these values in order to reach some leaf_node from the root_node of the tree for some given input-point. 
1) Should I only compare the features from the input-point with these bounds and then decide if I shold go to the right or left subtree? 
OR

2) Should i calculate for example the euclidian distance between the point and the node point and if the result is less then the radius-value from the node_data-array ?

How can i interpret these values in order to reach the "right" leaf_node where i can find some nearest points

Please see the implementation notes(above the code) from the binary tree interface:  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi